Postgres trigger check if insert affected column
I have a table where some columns have to be "protected", meaning they should not be written to by most users. I want to enforce this with a trigger function (as there is additional logic to the decision if the user , not relevant here).
My problem is that I am not able to find out if a user attempted to insert into the protected column. My first idea was to check the value of the NEW variable. The problem: Columns can have default values of all kinds of types which would be included in the NEW, so a simple check for NULL (which could also be set by the user to overwrite a default value) will not do the trick.
What I would like to avoid:

encoding the default value of the column into the code of the trigger function as this reduces maintainability and since I'm automatically generating the code for the trigger function and the column could have any data type the code generation could get pretty complex.
making a query to INFORMATION_SCHEMA to load the default of the column. Doing this for every insert seems pretty wasteful to me.

One possible solution that I see:

making an IMMUTABLE function that accesses the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to load the default value for the column. As far as I understand postgres should only make the query once and not for every insert since the result of the function call is cached.

Are there any better solutions? Is there any way to directly check if an INSERT affected a specific column?

Could you not use information_schema.columns in the code that generates the trigger's?

I could do that, yes. But imagine the column being of type bytea with a default value of a few kilobytes. Then I'd somehow have to render this content into the code of my trigger function.I know that having a bytea with such a default value is pretty unlikely, but what it comes down to is that I want an approach that works universally, no matter what type the column is and what default value it has.

FWIW, I tried using the default keyword in the trigger (see Fiddle1). But I believe that the function called by the trigger has no clue what table / column it concerns and hence is unaware of what default to use. I tried a similar construct in Db2 11.1 (see Fiddle2) and it works fine there.
If your protected columns should be protected from everyone you could use a generated always column:
create table T 
( x int not null generated always as identity
, y int generated always as ( 36 ) STORED
, z char(12) default 'a'  
);

But that will yield an error if anyone tries to set a value for that column, so I guess that won't fit your needs
I would look into column access control for this kind of problem, see How to implement Column and Row level security in PostgreSQL as a starter

Thank you for the effort! Unfortunatelly I need to allow some users to insert into the protected columns so a generated column is no option. I've also already read the article that you linked. The problem is that it looks like the method only works if you have different sql users where some should have permissions on the column and others should not. In my case sql roles/users are not used, my criteria for the decision if a user is allowed to write to the column or not is in the variables of the sql session. So I need custom logic.
